# Solve $\tan\left(\arccos\left(\frac{-\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)\right)$ without calculator

Tags: trigonometry

This is a question from the practice exercises of Barron's AP Calculus.

The directions state that I cannot use a calculator. (No trig tables I think, since those are not allowed in the exam)

So, how to solve

$$\tan\left(\arccos\left(\frac{-\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)\right)$$

without using a calculator? (With a knowledge of basic trig values like 0,30,45,60,90)

Comment: Do you mean $arccos \left( \frac{-\sqrt{2}}{2} \right)$? Because $arccos(-\sqrt{2})$ is not defined.

Comment: Oops, fixed it :)

Comment: Use frac for fractions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be written wrong, there is no real way to solve $\cos x=\sqrt2$.

If the task were $\tan(\arccos(-\sqrt2/2))$ then one knows from the elementary trig values that $\cos x=-\sqrt2/2$ has the solutions $x=\pm 135°$, so that $\arccos(-\sqrt2/2)=\frac{3\pi}4$ and the tangent of that is $-1$.

Comment: By http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values, $x=135^\circ$

Comment: Yes, that is the difference between solving a trig. equation and evaluating an inverse trig. function.

Answer (score 5):

The values of $\arccos x$ are, by definition, in the interval $[0,\pi]$; since $x=-\sqrt{2}/2<0$, we have $\pi/2<\arccos x<\pi$, where the tangent is negative.

Since
$$
\tan^2y=\frac{1-\cos^2y}{\cos^2 y}
$$
we can write, in the particular case where $y=\arccos(-\sqrt{2}/2)$,
$$
\tan \arccos(-\sqrt{2}/2)=
\frac{\sqrt{1-\cos^2y}}{\cos y}=
\frac{\sqrt{1-1/2}}{-\sqrt{2}/{2}}=-1
$$

Comment: Nice approach to the question! +1

Answer (score 1):

$\cos x=-\sqrt2/2$ has the solutions $x= 135°, 225°$ because $\cos$ is $<0 $ in second and third and quadrants. $ \tan $ is positive in third, first quadrants. So answer is -1 and + 1 respectively. But -1 is encountered first in counterclockwise direction, so can be taken as first choice.

Comment: Right, thanks, corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Draw a triangle. Cosine is adjacent over hypotenuse, so make a right triangle with angle $\theta$, adjacent side $-\sqrt{2}$ and hypotenuse $2$ (you can think of the negative sign as an indicator of orientation or just pretend that a side length can be negative, either way works).

Now, you want to find $\tan(\theta)$. Tangent is opposite over adjacent. You know adjacent is $-\sqrt{2}$ already, and you can solve for the opposite side using the Pythagorean theorem.

Opposite $= \sqrt{c^2 - a^2} = \sqrt{4 - 2} = \sqrt{2}$. You could also recognize that it's a 45 degree right triangle.

Then $\tan(\theta) = \frac{-\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}} = -1$.